# Data modeling. To split into separate tables or use role based authorization?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, data-modeling

I am trying to model as much of the data as possible for a new app before starting. The app will have Users & Spaces. The Spaces will have a number of Admin levels but will also have non-admin Members. The Space will associate Admins through `space_roles/space_admins` join table (name depends on the design decision I am trying to make). I am using a Role model to create the association between Spaces and Admins. This means the the space_roles table will be a three way join with `user_id, space_id and role_id` columns.

I plan to eventually build a bunch of tools around Spaces that the Members will have access to. These might not necessarily be restricted to Members of a certain Space. There most likely will be cases further down the road where Members of one Space can interact across organizational boundaries with Members of another Space using the Space as the scope (e.g. a fan of one sports team could join in on a discussion on the wall of another sports team where sports team is an analogy for Space).

My question is should I just create another Role called 'member' or should I break members out into another model (Member?) with an association through space_members? Please explain the advantages/disadvantages of your recommendation as best as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Admin` users are a subset of your `Users`, and it's possible for Users to become, or stop being, Admins, then keep them in the same table.

If your users (admins or not) can participate in more than one of your spaces, you probably want a single users table, and a separate users_spaces join table.  That table might have this layout.

```
    user_id       part of the primary key
    space_id      the rest of the primary key
    role          1 = contributor to the space, 2=member, 3=admin 4=owner etc
```

If users and admins are entirely distinct sets of people, then use two two tables and keep them separate. For example, if you were doing health care, and they were Nurses and Patients, you would definitely keep them separate, because they are subject to different confidentiality rules.

Comment: Great stuff. I went for the Users table with the triple join table (user, space, role) in the end. You have validated my decision. Much appreciated.